# Basic Android XML Error

Tags: android, xml

Here's a screenshot pertaining to the error I'm encountering

How can I fix this ?

[image: error]

I'd really appreciate some help

This is the XML code :

```
 <?xml​version="1.0" ​encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout​xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
​​​    android:orientation="vertical"
​​​​    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
​​​    ​android:layout_height="fill_parent"​>
    <TextView​​
​​​​    android:layout_width="fill_parent"​
​​​​    android:layout_height="wrap_content"​
​​​​    android:text="@string/hello"​/>
​​​​
    <TextView
​​​​    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
​​​​    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
​​​​    android:text="This is my first Android Application!" />
    <Button
​​​​    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
​​​​    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
​​​​    android:text="And this is a clickable button!" />
​​​​
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The first element in your XML is covered up by the error. Can you copy the XML into your question?

Comment: Yeah it looks fine like this, have you played around in the R file? Maybe just copy paste the code in here and don't have the error cover it up :)

Comment: @MCeley <?xml​version=”1.0”​encoding=”utf-8”?> is the XML involved

Comment: @AndersVedalPettersen Nope.Haven't touched the R file

Comment: Add a space in there between xml and version <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> Could be something else wrong.  The first layout element is still covered up.  Can you post the full XML?

Comment: yeah , tried doing that , sadly that doesn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is no string named "hello" in `Strings.xml` (in res->values).

Please check, probably this should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes!! Solved it.Thanks a ton :D

Answer (score 3):

```
LinearLayout​xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Needs to be

```
LinearLayout ​xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Without that space, the first XML tag is invalid.

Full XML would be:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is my first Android Application!" />

    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="And this is a clickable button!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try it now.  For some reason if I copy and pasted your XML in, it wouldn't work. But, if I typed it up myself exactly, then it works.  I think there might be something wrong with wherever it was originally pasted from.

Comment: I looked through your copy and pasted text using a hex editor and some characters came up as invalid so it appears to be an encoding issue with the copied characters.  If you copy and paste the XML from my post, it should work.